# Discord.js checking for mention in args

Tags: discord.js

Hey so I am making a discord bot and when I use this to check for mention: `message.mentions.members.first();` it will look for mention in whole message user has sent. I am trying to work this out because if user send message ?ban bla bla bla @user it will work. I want to check for mention only in `args[0]`. Is that possible? I am using discord v12. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what i found to work...

```js
if(args[0].slice(2).slice(0, -1) !== message.mentions.users.first()?.id) {
  return message.reply("Please start with a user...")
}
```

the `args[0].slice(2).slice(0, -1)` if a mention... will be the id of the first mention... and if the mention is the first arg, it will also be the first mention. So what I did was took ID of the first mention and compared it to the sliced args[0] to see if they match, else it will return telling them to please start with a user... Make sure to keep the `?` in `message.mentions.users.first()?.id` just in the case of no mention in the message, it will not cause an error to the process and will also return the please start with a user message.

Answer (score 0):

[Mentions](https://discordjs.guide/miscellaneous/parsing-mention-arguments.html#how-discord-mentions-work)

`USERS_PATTERN` uses RegEx for checking if `string` mentions about a `User`. If `string` matches with the pattern it returns `true`, otherwise returns `false`.

```
const { MessageMentions: { USERS_PATTERN } } = require('discord.js');

...
  if (!args[0].match(USERS_PATTERN)) return message.channel.send("Please mention a user");
...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).